# How to retrieve BlobStore file name from BlobReferenceProperty?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore, blobstore

I'm having a hard time understanding how to do something that should be straightforward.

```
class Spam(db.Model):
    egg = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty(blobstore.BlobKey, required=False)


class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        spam = models.Spam(egg=blob_info.key())
        spam.put()
```

So far so good right?  Now I want to display the file.

```
egg_blob = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(spam.egg) #error below is thrown here

self.redirect('/serve/%s' % egg_blob.key())


BadArgumentError: Expected str or BlobKey; received <google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.BlobInfo object at 0x3ed8970> (a BlobInfo)
```

What am I missing?  spam.egg, IS a BlobKey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I think egg_blob (aka spam.egg) is a BlobInfo.  Once you have spam.egg I don't think you need to go back to the blobstore for it, do you?  Have you tried just using the spam.egg reference? i.e. do

```
self.redirect('/serve/%s' % spam.egg.key())
```

Comment: Ah you're right!  I was over-thinking it - it dereferences egg to a BlobInfo and then you call the key normally.